# More efficient way to return errors in .NET Web Api 2 iHttpActionResult object?

Tags: c#, rest, httpresponse, asp.net-web-api2

I want to return an HTTP error code along with a JSON object in my service. But I cannot find a straightforward way to do this.

Right now this is the way I'm doing it:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new BadRequestError(ModelState)));
}
```

Basically I create an HTTPResponse, with the object I want to return, and then I "convert it" to an IHttpActionResult instance.

is this right? or should I be doing this another way?

Comment: returning an HTTP error code, by definition, means that there is no valid response. What are you trying to accomplish by returning both?

Comment: if by both you mean, the error code, and the json object, in the Json object I have the detail about why the request was a "Bad Request".

Comment: I think you might want to pick a different HTTP response than "Bad Request" -- that means the *HTTP Syntax* of the request was malformed, which isn't true. Otherwise, what you're doing should work as well as any other option. Thought I think you mean `HttpResponseMessage`? `ResponseMessage` is an Exchange class...

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that BadRequest is the correct error message, you can use the BadRequest(string error) method, as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn337086%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). To send the JSON, you would first parse this into a string and pass this as a parameter.

This would be done from the controller class, and is available as they are superclasses of the ApiController type. Also, please note there are methods for other error types also in the ApiController class.